# Calling a View from a UItableViewCell

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uitableview

I am trying to make my very first app. I have 6 files:

**LeftPanelViewController.h LeftPanelViewController.m LeftPanelViewController.xib ForecastViewController.h ForecastViewController.m ForecastViewController.xib**

Inside LeftPanelViewController.xib i have a view that contains a table view. i want to set a cell from the table view that i have in LeftPanelViewController.xib so when i press that cell i'll be able to call the view that i have inside the ForecastViewController.xib.

below the code the i have in LeftPanelTableViewController.m

```
#import "LeftPanelViewController.h"
#import "ForecastViewController.h"


@interface LeftPanelViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UITableView *myTableView;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UITableViewCell *cellMain;
@property (copy, nonatomic) NSArray *MRP;

@end

@implementation LeftPanelViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

Array = [[ NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[Array addObject:@"Forecast"];
[Array addObject:@"Inventory"];

}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
return [Array count];
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *SimpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableIdentifier";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:
SimpleTableIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]
initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle
reuseIdentifier:SimpleTableIdentifier];

//add an image to the tablecell
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Icon.png"];
cell.imageView.image = image;

}
cell.textLabel.text = [Array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

if (indexPath.row < 7) {
cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"Account";
} else {
cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"Settings";
}
return cell;
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
[super viewDidUnload];
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark View Will/Did Appear

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
[super viewWillAppear:animated];
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
[super viewDidAppear:animated];
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark View Will/Did Disappear

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
[super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}

- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
[super viewDidDisappear:animated];
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Array Setup


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark UITableView Datasource/Delegate

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
return 2;
}


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Default System Code

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
if (self)
{
}
return self;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

if ([[Array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqual:@"Forecast"]) {

ForecastViewController *Forecast = [[ ForecastViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ForecastViewController" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:Forecast animated:YES];

}


[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}



@end
```

Comment: What is the problem???

Comment: when i press the designated cell nothing happens. xcode doesn't show any warnings or errors in my code i think i am missing something but because of my lack of experience i cant tell what.

Comment: i have a cell called forecast in a tableview inside LeftPanelViewController.xib. i thought this piece of code that i have in LeftPanelViewController.m would allow me to select that cell and bring me to the view that i have in ForecastViewControler.xib if ([[Array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqual:@"Forecast"]) {

ForecastViewController *Forecast = [[ ForecastViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ForecastViewController" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:Forecast animated:YES];

}

Comment: Use a breakpoint or NSLog to see if [self.navigationController pushViewController:Forecast animated:YES]; gets called

Comment: i think you should use :isEqualToString:@"Forecast" instead isEqual:@"Forecast"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:Forecast animated:YES];
```

use

```
[self presentViewController:Forecast animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH!! that just solved my problem!! I spent 4 days trying to figure out what the problem was and that just did it!!

Comment: Although this worked, they are not the same thing. The first are trying to present the view as push inside a navigation controller; the second is presinting it modally. Please see this for more information: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ModalViewControllers/ModalViewControllers.html

Answer (score 1):

Even if modal controller did the trick, it may be not what you want. Nothing was happening because your view controller is nil. Probably you are using "Single view app" template from xCode and it has no navigation controller. If you want one, you should create it like [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:] and set your's window root controller to newly created navigationcontroller.